# How to convert DataTable Cell Value to Object Array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, datatable

Here is my code,

```
object[] objrow = new object[]{"Test","test1","test2","test3","test4"};

object[] objrow1 = new object[]{"Test","test1","test2","test3","test4"};

 DataTable dtentercodemfm = new DataTable();
 dtentercodemfm.Columns.Add("objrow");
 dtentercodemfm.Columns.Add("objrow1");
 dtentercodemfm.Rows.Add(objrow, objrow1);
```

While Getting this Data,

```
object[] objrow = (object[])dtentercodemfm.Rows[0][0];
object[] objrow1 = (object[])dtentercodemfm.Rows[0][1];
```

Gives me error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object[]'.
```

How to Solve.

Comment: I think `dtentercodemfm.Rows[0][0]` returns `string` there is no explicit conversation from `string` to _object array_. Why not just use `object objrow = (object)dtentercodemfm.Rows[0][0];` instead? Then you can add these values to an array.

Comment: It's an object Array then how to use object?can u explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work (Tried and tested).

While creating columns do this

```
dtentercodemfm.Columns.Add("objrow", typeof (object[]));
dtentercodemfm.Columns.Add("objrow1", typeof (object[]));
```

[image]

**Why this works**

Because when you do not provide type while creating column, default type is taken which is String. So data was storing in DB as string which was "System.Object".

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
object[] objrow = (object[]) Convert.ToString(dtentercodemfm.Rows[0][0]).Split(',') ;
```

Comment: @user1463105: Read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you need to write your question like this

```
    dtentercodemfm.Columns.Add("objrow");

    dtentercodemfm.Rows.Add(objrow);
    dtentercodemfm.Rows.Add(objrow1);

    dtentercodemfm.AcceptChanges();
```

Add 2 rows and 1 columns,
You're doing reverse, adding 1 column, and adding 2 rows